# finding value of closest hidden field, located above user click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab the value of a hidden field that resides above each group of LI's with javascript, I cannot use jQuery because of an unreasonable client's concerns (believe me, I've tried, they just don't want to "risk" adding a library)... anyway...

The list would look something like this:

```
<input id="hidden1" type="hidden" value="5" class="includeds">
<h3>header</h3>
<ul class="groups">
    <li><input id="li1" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li2" type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li3" type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="value()"></li>
</ul>
<input id="hidden2" type="hidden" value="3" class="includeds">
<h3>header2</h3>
<ul class="groups">
    <li><input id="li4" type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li5" type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li6" type="checkbox" value="6" onclick="value()"></li>
</ul>
```

So if I click on checkbox `li1`, I want to retrieve the value `"5"` from the hidden field above it.

If I click `li5`, I want to get the value of `"2"` from the first hidden field above it, etc, etc.

in a previous SO question some amazing people helped me do this with jQuery:

```
if($(this).closest('ul').prevAll('.includeds:first').val() !== '0') { 
      // logic here
}
```

but when presented to the client, I ran into the aforementioned complaints. So now I need to do the same thing with javascript vanilla. I appreciate any help or pointers you guys could provide. I apologize for asking the same question twice, between jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, the jQuery code I'd use would be:

```
$(this).parent().prev().prev().val()
```

With that in mind, all you have to do is rewrite the code to correct plain javascript entities.

The result would be something like:

```
function getParent(node){
    return node.parentNode;
}

function getPrev(node){
    do { // loop to find the previous node that is an element
        node = node.previousSibling;
    }while(node && node.nodeType != 1);
    return node;
}

getPrev(getPrev(getParent(this))));
```

Comment: The point of the question was they can't use jQuery anymore and need straight javascript

Comment: And my point of my answer is that just because he can't *use* jQuery doesn't mean he can't *think* jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use jQuery then complex queries like the on you mentioned become much more difficult.  In liue of jQuery it's easiest to reference elements by their `ID` tag or by a class filter (depending on the scenario).

Here i would say the best bet is to hard code the given `input` ID into the `onclick` function.

HTML

```
<input id="hidden2" type="hidden" value="3" class="includeds">
<h3>header2</h3>
<ul class="groups">
    <li><input id="li4" type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="value('hidden2')"></li>
    <li><input id="li5" type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="value('hidden2')"></li>
    <li><input id="li6" type="checkbox" value="6" onclick="value('hidden2')"></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
function value(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementByID(id);
  ...
}
```